# Draw a cell of UITableView give a visual error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I write a code to draw card in a UITableView, each card need to draw itself and have a custom rowheight in the exemple a draw 2 card in 240 height and 8 other with 240/2 of height.

I give you a screen of the problem :

[image]

The last but one card have a strange design. When I print the bounds of the frame of it, this show me the same size that the other ...

I give you my code where I draw the card :

```
func drawBasiqCard() -> CGFloat{
    if(cardView.subviews.count == 0){
        self.addSubview(cardView)
        cardView.frame = CGRect(marginCardWidth,
                                marginCardHeight,
                                self.bounds.size.width - (marginCardWidth*2),
                                basiqCardtHeight - (marginCardHeight*2))
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        print(cardView.bounds.size.height)
    }
    if(self.ShadowLayerCard == nil){
        let rounding = CGFloat.init(10)
        let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
        self.ShadowLayerCard = shadowLayer
        shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: cardView.bounds, cornerRadius: rounding).cgPath
        shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xffcc00).cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 0)
        cardView.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
    }
    return cardView.bounds.size.height + (marginCardHeight*2)
}
```

So my question is, the code above is good ? Or my error are not here ? Where is the code can be produce this visual error ?
If you need the code of the UITableView I can show you.

Thank for your reply.

Comment: Please share the tableview code

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you set the shadow of the view before it's bounds has been set.

Your current design is not good, you should add a shadow to the `contentView` in `init` and then change the `contentView`'s frame(add some padding) in `layoutsubviews`.

Here is an example:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    contentView.do {
      $0.backgroundColor = .white
      $0.addShadow(ofColor: .black, radius: 1.5, offset: .zero, opacity: 0.1)
      $0.cornerRadius = 6
    }
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    contentView.pin.all(UIEdgeInsets(inset: 5))
  }

  override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

    contentView.backgroundColor = highlighted ? UIColor(rgb: 217) : .white
  }
}
```

It looks like:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ok, but how can I make that because i need a custom height for 5 different style of cell ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. 

If it's just a different height, then you can return the different height directly in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`. If those cells are different styles, you can customize them or inherit from a base class, depending on the style of your cell and the design of the code.

As for the height, you can declare a protocol that contains the `static var rowHeight: CGFloat { get set }`, and then each cell conforms and implements it. Then you can return the `rowHeight` directly in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`.

Any questions can continue to reply to me.